# Least squares in matrix form demonstration

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

I want to know why $$\min ||AX-B||^2 <=> A^tAX = A^tB$$ and I'm having a hard time finding a demonstration that I can understand. I'm pretty sure I have to start by doing $Y=AX$ and $B = B_1 + B_2$ but any attempt to go beyond that has got me stuck.

Comment: I was supposed to say that it's equivalent.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really know how to proceed with just what you said.

Comment: I added a geometric answer below, let's start with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one approach:

Let $S = {\cal R} A$, the range space of $A$. This is a (closed) subspace, so
we can write the problem as $\min_{s \in S} \|s-b\|^2$, that is, finding the closest point to $b$ in the subspace $S$.

Remember, for every point in $s \in S$, there is some (possible many) $x$ such that $s = Ax$.

It is straightforward to show (using a compactness argument, for example)
that the derived problem has a solution (in fact it is unique). It is also
straightforward to show that the solution $s$ satisfies
$s-b \bot S$ (draw a picture to see the geometry). That is $s$ is the orthogonal
projection of $b$ onto $S$.

To see this analytically, choose $x \in S$, then we have $\|s-b\|^2 \le \|s+tx-b\|^2$ for all $t$. If we expand this we get
$\|s-b\|^2 \le t^2 \|x\|^2 + \|s-b\|^2 + 2 t \langle s-b, x \rangle$, which gives $t \|x\|^2 + 2 \langle s-b, x \rangle$ if we divide by $t \neq 0$. Letting $t \to 0$ gives $\langle s-b, x \rangle \ge 0$. Since $-x \in S$ as well, we get $\langle s-b, x \rangle =0$ for all $x \in S$, which is
$s-b \bot S$.

In particular, we have $\langle u, s-b \rangle = 0$ for all $u \in S$.
Since $s$ has the form $s = Ax$ for some $x$ and similarly $u=Ay$, this gives$\langle Ay, Ax-b \rangle = \langle y, A^T(Ax-b) \rangle =0$. Since
this is true for all $y$, we have $A^T(Ax-b) = 0$.

Comment: Geometric interpretation is my weakness in linear algebra, lol. s in this case would be the orthogonal projection projection of b on the subspace S? http://thejuniverse.org/PUBLIC/LinearAlgebra/LOLA/dotProd/projDeriv.png 
In that picture, s would be proj(u,v), b would be v and s-b = proj(u,v) - v, right? 

Sadly I wasn't able to understand what you did afterwards. Where did you get that ⟨t, s−b⟩ = 0 from? What is Ay? Why ⟨Ay,Ax−b⟩=⟨y,AT(Ax−b)⟩?

Comment: @xsr: I added some detail above, I'm not sure it clarifies things. Two vectors are orthogonal **iff** $\langle x, y \rangle = 0$. A vector $v$ is orthogonal to $S$, written $v \bot S$ **iff** $\langle v,s \rangle = 0$ for all $s \in S$. Remember that $S$ is the range space of $A$.

Comment: I didn't understand how you did this: $\|s+tx-b\|^2$ = $t^2 \|x\|^2 + \|s-b\|^2 + 2 t \langle s-b, x \rangle$
and this: $\langle Ay, Ax-b \rangle = \langle y, A^T(Ax-b) \rangle$
Understood all the other things you've done though. Thank you so much for your patience.

Comment: The first follows from $\|x\|^2 = \langle x,x \rangle = x^T x$ (assuming $\mathbb{R}^n$), and then expanding. The definition of adjoint/transpose is $\langle Bx,y \rangle = \langle x, B^T y\rangle$, or you can use $\langle Ay, Ax-b\rangle = (Ay)^T (Ax-b) = y^T A^T (Ax-b)$.

Comment: I was aware of the first thing you said, but I didn't get how to apply it here.

Comment: For example, $\langle s-b +tx, s-b+tx \rangle = \langle s-b ,s-b \rangle +\langle tx, tx \rangle + \langle s-b, tx \rangle + \langle tx, s-b \rangle$.